# How can I copy empty folders from server to client

Tags: java, file, client-server

I have an client-server application. The sever app is on Ubuntu machine, an client app is on Windows. When I start my apps, the first thing to be done is to copy a specific folder from server to a specific location from client. The problem is I can not send through socket an empty folder,because the object sent through socket ar fileEvent object. Does anyone have any idea how to send an empty folder? I attached the functions that send files from server to client.

```
                    public void locateFiles(String s,String d) throws IOException {
            File srcDir = new File(s);
            if (!srcDir.isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println("Source directory is not valid ..Exiting the client");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            File[] files = srcDir.listFiles();
            fileCount = files.length;
            if (fileCount == 0) {
                   sendFile(srcDir.getAbsolutePath()/*, fileCount - i - 1*/,d,s);
            }

            for(File f : files){
                if(f.isDirectory())
                {
                    locateFiles(f.toString(),d+f.getName()+"/");
                }
                else {
                   sendFile(f.getAbsolutePath()/*, fileCount - i - 1*/,d,s);
                }
            }
      }

      public void sendFile(String fileName,String desti,String su) {
            fileEvent = new FileEvent();
            fileEvent.setDestinationDirectory(desti);
            fileEvent.setSourceDirectory(su);
            File file = new File(fileName);
            fileEvent.setFilename(file.getName());
            DataInputStream diStream = null;
            try {
                diStream = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
                long len = (int) file.length();
                byte[] fileBytes = new byte[(int) len];

                int read = 0;
                int numRead = 0;
                while (read < fileBytes.length && (numRead = diStream.read(fileBytes, read,
                        fileBytes.length - read)) >= 0) {
                    read = read + numRead;
                }
                fileEvent.setFileData(fileBytes);
                fileEvent.setStatus("Success");
                diStream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                fileEvent.setStatus("Error");
            }

            sendFlag();
            sendDest(desti);

            try {
                outputStream.writeObject(fileEvent);
                outputStream.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }               
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the folder is empty. If it is empty, create a new folder on your client. A simple work around :)

Comment: Thank you, I was thinging something like you sugested,but I was still tring to send a path as a FileEvent object. This was the mistake, I will send the path simply, so the client will create the empty folder.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you create empty folder by your client side code?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
if (folder is empty) then
  create temporary file in folder
  temp_file_created <- true
endif

copy folder to destination

if (temp_file_created) then
  delete temp file from source machine
  delete temp file from destination machine
  temp_file_created <- false
endif
```

should work.

Comment: This is a good idea too, but it is a bit hard to implement for my app. thanks.